# Does the data property of Angular's router pass through the url?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm thinking of adding large json files to each route in an angular app (e.g. the text contents of a full page with classes and attributes defined). From angular's documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration):

> The data property in the third route is a place to store arbitrary
>   data associated with this specific route. The data property is
>   accessible within each activated route. Use it to store items such as
>   page titles, breadcrumb text, and other read-only, static data. You'll
>   use the resolve guard to retrieve dynamic data later in the guide.

These seem like rather small amounts of data to add with the "data" property.

**Is it ok to add as much static data as I want with this property without any consequences?**

Concerns:

- Does the router pass it through the url (e.g. maybe I might go pass max characters allowed in a url?)
- Are there any security issues involved with the data property?

Comment: i'm not aware of any security risks, but i would not consider this best practice. why can't you retrieve the data `OnInit` in the target components?

Comment: @jahller It's because in the project, the component is being reused throughout multiple routes. It's also easier to access the route activated by knowing about it already in the routes array at a router module like (app-routing.module) then have to look for it all over again in OnInit()